# Should I detach entity from EF context when exposed it through Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using EF5 code-first approach and I am just wondering should I detach entity from EF context when exposed it through the Web API?

Let's say I have API action method

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var user = _userRepository.GetById(id);

    if (user != null)
    {
        // detach here???
        _userRepository.Detach(user);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, user);
    }

    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, string.Format("No user with id={0} is found", id));
}
```

Actually what are the best practices for that? Should I create the projection of the entity and then exposed it?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't send the entity back.  I'd create a basic class for it, and use AutoMapper (or something like it) to map the entity to the DTO class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Detach is necessary, it will automatically be detached when you ever get it back.

But considering that you only use it in a Request/Response environment, then it is sensible to load it with the [NoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj556203) option in the first place. Eliminate overhead for functionality you will never use.